# FetchRequest to fetch items from a one to many relationship?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two entities, one called projects and one called tasks, and projects can have many tasks to them. I have a fetch request that can fetch all tasks, but I want to modify it so that it only fetches tasks from the observed project.

Here are my two classes with the one to many relationship:

```
extension ProjectItem {

    @NSManaged public var projectId: UUID
    @NSManaged public var projectTitle: String
    @NSManaged public var projectDateCreated: Date
    @NSManaged public var task: NSSet

}
```

```
extension TaskItem {

    @NSManaged public var completedDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var createdDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var isComplete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var project: ProjectItem?
}
```

Here is the basic fetch request I currently have that fetches all completed tasks. How can I modify this fetch request to only fetch tasks that belong to an observed project?

```
    @FetchRequest(entity: TaskItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.createdDate, ascending: false)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isComplete == %@", NSNumber(value: false))) var taskItems: FetchedResults<TaskItem>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
// assuming
@ObservedObject var currentProject: ProjectItem

// ...

NSPredicate(format: "project.projectId == %@ AND isComplete == %@", 
            currentProject.projectId, NSNumber(value: false))
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I get these two errors: "Argument type 'UUID' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'" and "Cannot use instance member 'currentProject' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" @Asperi